# Istio origin authentication stops working after cluster maintainance (GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

As the title shows, origin authentication of Istio failed after cluster maintainance last week.
I surveyed logs, but I couldn't find the clue to solve the problem.

I'd appreciate if anyone teaches me what the cause is or how to find out the effective logs.

I confirmed that a request to our web server was with a valid JWT, but the response was 401 unauthorized and its message was `origin authentication failed` .
And after recreating pods, origin authentication worked again.
Besides, I found out that requests failed after the maintainance of GKE by checking the access logs
Therefore, I thought sidecars (envoy) had problems after the maintainance, but couldn't find any envoy's helpful logs.

I installed Istio as GKE add-on, and versions are following.
Origin authentication had been working fine for two months.

- GKE master version: 1.16.8-gke.15
- Nodepool version: 1.15.9-gke.24

Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: What do you mean by re-creating pods? Did you check the logs for Istiod and coredns pods?

Comment: Can you see any log from application side?

Comment: @redzack Thank you for the reply! I mean I run Rails app pods that contain istio-proxy as a deployment, so I deleted pods to recreate new pods.  
  
> Did you check the logs for Istiod and coredns pods?   
I did'n t. Now I checked kubedns logs and I found the error  
`Unable to decode an event from the watch stream: http2: server sent GOAWAY and closed the connection; LastStreamID=29423, ErrCode=NO_ERROR, debug=""`  
I cannot find this error before the day when the probelm happend, So this error is related to the problem somehow.

Comment: @KoopaKiller Thank you for the reply! No, I can't see any log. I can see the log of istio-proxy for each request of my API, which says the response is 401. So, isito-proxy received requests, but they were rejected by origin authentication.

Comment: So, after recreated your application pod everything worked fine? There is some way to reproduce the same scenario using a simple app image?

Comment: @KoopaKiller Yes, now everything works fine, but I'm not sure the same incident doesn"t happen again. If I specify a pod that uses a simple app image to use origin authentication, it will be affected by the same problem. But what is difficult is to make the same incident happen on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved recreating the application's pod.

Since there is no way to reproduce the same bahavior from ISTIO side, I recommend you to [open a Issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on GCP to investigation.